# Want to Pass data with accessorybuttontapped

Tags: xcode, uitableview, segue

I have the below code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *recordCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
DetailViewController.record = [self recordByName:recordCell.textLabel.text];
```

it work perfectly. but i want to replace UITableViewCell with RecordTableViewCell so I can use recordLabel instead of textLabel.
The code should be

```
RecordTableViewCell *recordCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
DetailViewController.record = [self recordByName:recordCell.recordLabel.text];
```

But it does not work. It say "incompatible pointer types initializing RecordTableViewCell with an expression of type UITableViewCell"...
Please help. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a cast to your code like this:

```
RecordTableViewCell *recordCell = (RecordTableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```